# Windows 2003: Dropbox needs permission to update

Tags: windows-server-2003, dropbox

I have a Windows 2003 server box with dropbox installed. Every once in a while, it pops up a dialog window asking for permission to update itself. Everytime it asks for permission, it renders the network adapter unuseable and I need to reboot the server.

In Dropbox Preferences there is no option to set update to automatic or manual either.

How do I disable this confirmation popup dialog box window and have dropbox automatically update itself?

Comment: have you thought of using a different cloud storage provider?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the dropbox tray icon I'm sure you can right click > preferences > general > Untick show desktop notifications?

Comment: it is already unticked `[ ] Show desktop notifications`